# In Rails how to strip the first two parts of a string separated by '/' (URL)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have **several strings (URLs)** like this :

```
2014/navam/dasa-paaramitha
```

I need to remove the first two parts `2014/navam` of every string. Every string have the same format, the year followed by the name of the month in sinhala and the name of the post. How can I do this? (Searching for the two exact parts `2014` and `navam` and deleting them won't work because there are URLs from 2013 and from all the other months)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regexp:

```
=> reg = /\d+\/\w+\//
=> "2014/navam/dasa-paaramitha".gsub(reg, '')
=> "dasa-paaramitha"
```

http://rubular.com/r/BpTG70eGWS

Answer (score -1):

Ugly way without using regexp.

```
2.1.0 :008 > str = "2014/navam/dasa-paaramitha"
 => "2014/navam/dasa-paaramitha"
2.1.0 :009 > str.split("/")[2]
 => "dasa-paaramitha"
```